# Connecting two CC/CV chargers in series with different curent ratings

Tags: current, lithium-ion, charger

I have a 26 series Li-ion battery pack of 96V.

I have 2 CC/CV chargers of 48V each.

My Google search shows that I can connect the two 48V chargers in series to charge the 96V battery, but I have doubts because one of the chargers is 2.5A and the other is 4A.

Would the 2.5A charger get burned if I connect it in series with the 4A charger, or will the 4A charger automatically work at 2.5A giving a total output of 96V 2.5A?

UPDATE:
The 26s battery pack has ANT BMS which balances the charging and discharging.

The two chargers in question are not basic transformers. They have been used to charge 2 x 48V (13s) Hailong battery packs. These 2 batteries had their own BMS circuits.

Comment: Series operating if floating might work but unless each cell is matched during high current, the state of charge % can get unbalanced and cause problems near Vmax and Vmin. This is why Cell balancers are used, otherwise be conservative and measure differences if possible. 1% is significant as each cycle it gets worse in an exponential way if over or under charged

Comment: It would be the same if 26 people were pulling a rope apart and the weakest link determines what happens if one person is over-stressed. You need a balanced pack to live a long life or just expect a shorter life cycles when pulling at max current. Balancers are key for large series strings. Likewise the chargers will be limited by the weaker one. Nice try but sub-optimal solution.

Comment: The battery pack has ANT BMS balancer. So it is possible to charge with these 2 Chargers in series at the rate of lower ampere charger? Battery has no issues with it as I see all the cell levels on my phone via BMS Bluetooth. And the ANT BMS is perfectly capable of protecting the battery. It's the Chargers damaging each other that I am worried about. I want to make a switch combination to use the 2 Chargers as series for 96V and as parallel for the 48V batteries when needed. (NOT at the same time :D) Thanks

Comment: Sounds OK.......  check temperatures

Answer (score 1):

No, especially if the chargers have intelligent control.

If this was just two transformers then the basic idea would work.

Comment: @Roguenite, the "success" of your experiment has to do with the fact that the battery never draw more than 2A current from the charger (the BMS limited it). If this experiment were to be done to charge a battery that draw more than the capacity limit of 2.5A of one of the chargers, it would damage it unless it has a current limit in it. Remember: it is the load (the battery) that determines the current. In your case, the battery BMS limited the maximum current to 2A. What would have happened if you have charged a different battery, with or without a BMS, that would draw more than 2.5A?

Comment: Edit: Because your chargers are CC/CV the current would have been limited by the 2.5A charger.

Comment: Yes, my initial concern was which CC charger will decide the AMPS. I am glad it was the lower current one. Have been testing the charger for over 15 days now. No issues. I only use it at work place in daytime.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating the results after I've tested my charger setup. It was a complete success.
Two 48V chargers connected in serial gives an output of 96V and 2A current. The BMS of the 26s 25Ah battery packs automatically stops charging at battery peak voltage.

The 2 chargers changes the red LED to green once BMS stops accepting further charging. I have even left the chargers connected  for 11+ hours, no problems.
Chargers don't heat.
Battery doesn't heat.
BMS doesn't heat.

All a success.

Thanks Tony Stewart for helping me in the comments

Comment: "success" for a battery charger should not be judged by a single charge. Down voting because I don't want future readers to think this is a good idea.

Comment: Have been using it everyday for 15 days now.